# How to Integrate external Camera device to Android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, libusb, usb-drive

Requirement:-
I have to make a android accessibility service application which take camera frames through any USB Camera Device.

1. Camera should be always turn on.
2. Try to use camera2 Api to connect with external camera device but I don't get reference.
3. https://source.android.com/docs/core/camera/external-usb-cameras
   I followed this article but I am not able to find location of file where to edit these settings.
4. Now I am trying to edit
   https://github.com/saki4510t/UVCCamera
   This code?
   But still I am not success.

will any one guide me to how to do that?
thanks

Comment: "I followed this article but I am not able to find location of file where to edit these settings" -- that documentation is for modifying the operating system itself.

Comment: Yes do you have any idea how to integrate external camera

Comment: I use https://github.com/saki4510t/UVCCamera github project to get exteternal camera frame. But now i have problem how to integrate it as system service.

Comment: "But now i have problem how to integrate it as system service" -- unless you are building your own version of Android as part of your own firmware, you cannot create a system service.

Comment: I got something about accessibility service in android from there. I can start my camera service as background process. I don't know I am right or wrong but I think it will work for my requirements.